# Save file locally in jupyterhub notebook running on EMR cluster

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr, jupyterhub

When using Jupyterhub application interface (via SSH tunneling) on Amazon EMR, the default file explorer says `/user/jovyan/tree`. What directory is this and how can I save a file (say a matplotlib figure) from within the notebook to this local space? The usual tricks like

```
os.chdir(sys.path[0])
print(os.getcwd())
```

show `/mnt/tmp`, which does not actually appear to be the local directory.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are running in `EMR notebook` is actually saved on `s3`. By default, it is often in a bucket named something like `emr-resources`, under the notebooks folder.

Try checking your s3 and I believe if you save a file from within an emr notebook, it will be available save in s3 (and available next time)

Comment: I don't see any buckets named that way, only logfiles

Comment: they can be of different name, but they would be there as s3 holds the contents of an emr notebook